# Scala: How to override tuple equals() method for arbitrary element types?

Tags: scala, overriding, tuples, equals

I have a map with values keyed by tuple. In my case I need tuples match irrespective of elements order so, for example, I need this to hold:

```
(1, 2) == (2, 1) is true
```

How to override tuple `equals` operator, so for any types X, Y :

```
(a:X, b:Y) == (b:Y, a:X) is true  ?
```

*Corrected later*: Another idea would be to write my own `Pair` class with required behavior. How `equals()` override will look like in this case?

Comment: Another possibility is to add all permutations as Map entries (e.g. `(1,2)-> value` and `(2,1) -> value`), or to create a sorted tuple each time it is used as a key.

Comment: Good idea, thanks! Or add just one permutation, but check always for both permutations.

Comment: The type Pair is already a synonym for Tuple2, so you might want to pick another name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why not use `Set`? It has the equality semantics you want.

Comment: Using Set would preclude the two parts being equal, e.g. (1,1).  It would also allow more than two elements, and it wouldn't have an unapply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you don't really want to change the semantics of tuples, because the universe would implode.  You just want something *like* tuples -- except for their equality semantics.

Why not just use a case class?  Tuples are really just ready-made classes to hold a few things together when it isn't worth the trouble to define a class.  Well, if you want to change equality, I'd say it's worth the trouble!  Plus you can use more meaningful names than _1 and _2.

I don't know what those names would be, of course, but here's some code.  As Travis points out, messing with [equality](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html) is tricky, in part because you also have to think about the hash code.  Hopefully this is reasonable:

```
scala> case class Foo[T]( a:T, b:T ) {
  override def equals( that:Any ) = that match {
    case that:Foo[T] => ( that canEqual this ) && (
      this.a == that.a && this.b == that.b ||
      this.a == that.b && this.b == that.a
    )
    case _ => false
  }
  override def canEqual( that:Any ) = that.isInstanceOf[Foo[T]]
  override def hashCode = a.hashCode + b.hashCode
}
defined class Foo

scala> Foo(1,2) == Foo(1,2)
res15: Boolean = true

scala> Foo(1,2) == Foo(2,1)
res16: Boolean = true

scala> Foo(1,2) == Foo(2,2)
res17: Boolean = false

scala> collection.immutable.HashSet( Foo(0,1), Foo(1,0), Foo(1,2) )
res18: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[Foo[Int]] = Set(Foo(0,1), Foo(1,2))
```

Note that `res18` contains `Foo(1,0)` but not `Foo(0,1)` because of that definition of equality.

Comment: Overriding equality scares the hell out of me, and if you try to guess how many elements will be in `collection.immutable.HashSet(Foo(0, 1), Foo(1, 0))` given this definition, it may scare the hell out of you, too.

Comment: And just to be clear, since this is now the accepted answer: overriding `equals` without knowing exactly what you're doing is a very bad idea. If you don't also provide a consistent `hashCode`, for example, you're going to break a lot of stuff (including many of the standard library's collection types) in extremely hard-to-debug ways.

Comment: Yes, shame on me for not overriding hashCode when I changed equality!  Any other problems, Travis?

Comment: I don't think so? Don't take my word on that, though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't override the behavior defined for `Tuple2`.  After all, those two tuples are *not* equal, so you can't tell scala to say that they are.

You could define your own kind of tuple that has the equality property you want, but then you wouldn't be able to use the nice parentheses syntax.

The easiest way is to just define your own equality function that you call:

```
 def myEquals[X,Y](a: (X,Y), b: (Y,X)) = a._1 == b._2 && a._2 == b._1
```

So then you have:

```
 scala> myEquals((1,'a'), ('a',1))
 res0: Boolean = true
```

You could also define a *new* equality operator for Tuple2

```
implicit class NewEqualityTuple2[X,Y](a: (X,Y)) {
  def =<>=(b: (Y,X)) = a._1 == b._2 && a._2 == b._1
}
```

Giving this:

```
scala> (1,'a') =<>= ('a',1)
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer but it does not allow to use thus modified tuple as a key in Map collection from Scala 'standard' library. So  it looks like I need to write my own `Pair` class to get the desired behavior.Please see my  _corrected_ section

Comment: how about `def myEquals[X,Y](a: (X,Y), b: (Y,X)) = a == b.swap`?